# System says out of GPU memory, when I just got a new laptop

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, interface, gpu, system

I recently got a new laptop with a
[image]

Total Gaphics memory says:
[image]

My computer is struggling to render and says "GPU out of data".

My previous laptop had less ram and the graphics cards weren't as good but it never put out this message.
Are my settings incorrect?
Can someone please help me?

Comment: You should use OptiX with that graphics card, not CUDA. Try with that first. What is the memory used by your render?

Comment: Also deselect your integrated GPU on the processor and let us know if that fixes if it changing to OptiX doesnt immediately fix the issue.

I think to use CUDA you have to install special drivers.  At least I did on linux.

Comment: I was using OptiX before and that didn't work either! 
How do I deselect my integrated gpu on the prosessor?

Comment: Memory used is 196.96M per frame

Comment: I tried rendering another frame now on Optix and it says "System is out of GPU memory." again